# Concatenação de um campo da Select na função ADDTIME

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

```
"SELECT     at.codigoTurma, "
           "ADDTIME(t.horaInicioCurso, '00:01:00'), "
           "t.toleranciaCurso, "
           "t.horaFinalCurso "
"FROM       AlunosTurmas at "
"INNER JOIN Turmas t "
"ON         t.codigoTurma = at.codigoTurma "
"WHERE      at.matriculaAluno = :matricula "
"ORDER BY   t.horaInicioCurso"
```

Eu gostaria de utilizar o campo `t.toleranciaCurso`, na função `ADDTIME`, no lugar dos minutos.

```
t.tolerancia(INT), t.horaInicioCurso(TIME).
ADDTIME(t.horaInicioCurso, '00:' + t.toleranciaCurso + ':00') // soma apenas segundos
```

Comment: E por que não usa? Dá algum erro? Algum resultado errado? Que tipo são as colunas? No caso `t.toleranciaCurso` precisa ser do tipo `TIME` ou precisa converter para este tipo ((STR_TO_DATE)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date]). pela descrição da coluna, ela deveria ser deste tipo. Se não é, já tem um erro aí. Dá para arrumar isto? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html

Comment: desculpe n informar. t.horaInicioCurso(TIME), t.toleranciaCurso(int).
mas se eu tentar colocar, por exemplo:
ADDTIME(t.horaInicioCurso, '00:'+t.toleranciaCurso+':00)
ele soma segundos mesmo assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que o segundo parâmetro da função `ADDTIME()` precisa ser do tipo `TIME` e você quer usar uma coluna dot tipo `INT` precisa converter com a função [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time):

```
SEC_TO_TIME(t.toleranciaCurso * 60)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Conversion.sql).

Esta função espera o número de segundos, como você tem minutos, precisa converter para esta unidade de medida em uma aritmética simples.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!